# How to speed up bookdown generation?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, bookdown

I'm currently working on a book using bookdown. It uses some code snippets which take time to compile, execute and get output. I use the following commands to build HTML, PDF and EPUB files for the book:

```
Rscript -e "bookdown::render_book('index.Rmd', 'bookdown::gitbook')"
Rscript -e "bookdown::render_book('index.Rmd', 'bookdown::pdf_book')"
Rscript -e "bookdown::render_book('index.Rmd', 'bookdown::epub_book')"
```

So, every time the book files are generated the actual computation takes place increasing the overall generation time ×3.

Is there any way to produce some intermediate file on the first run and than use it to build HTML, PDF and EPUB outputs?

Comment: have you tried caching (i.e. `cache = TRUE`) in chunk options?

Comment: As mentioned in the bookdown book: https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/some-tips.html

Comment: @YihuiXie, yes that book is awesome! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to significantly reduce the regeneration time by adding the following snippet to my `index.Rmd`:

````
```{r include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(cache = TRUE)
```
````

Update:

As [Yuriy Barvinchenko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56541371/how-to-speed-up-bookdown-generation/56544953#comment99664818_56541371) and [Yihui Xie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56541371/how-to-speed-up-bookdown-generation/56544953#comment99675216_56544953) both suggested, it's better to [cache only time-consuming](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/some-tips.html) code chunks:

````
```{go time-sleep-demo cache = TRUE}
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Print("Hello ")
    time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
    fmt.Println("world!")
}
```
````

Comment: I suggest you only cache those time-consuming code chunks instead of all code chunks, because there is no free lunch in caching, e.g. https://yihui.name/en/2018/06/cache-invalidation/

Comment: @YihuiXie, thanks for the clarifications. My “book” is actually a learning course content for Go programming language, so I believe there would be no harm in caching all those “Hello, world!”, Fibonacci, and (especially) `time.Sleep` code snippets.