# Options for speeding up bookdown builds in code-heavy stats books

Tags: r, bookdown

My PI is building a large stats book using Bookdown for a machine learning course. We've been delighted with Bookdown so far but are still struggling with how to build it faster when we have small edits to make.

For example, we have one chapter listing assigned readings and homeworks. We'd like to update that page several times a week to add answer keys or additional readings, but it requires up to a half hour rebuilding the entire book.

We are already caching large code chunks. Helpful, but it requires knowing exactly what chunks are causing the slowdowns. Sometimes it's obvious, other times less so. And of course we also see that caching more than [minimally necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56541371/how-to-speed-up-bookdown-generation) is [not recommended](https://yihui.org/en/2018/06/cache-invalidation/).

I saw the issue was [raised in 2017](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/307) and endorsed by other stats book authors. It seems surprising there is still no built-in method for rebuilding a single book chapter, given how many stats books are built on Bookdown.

Without that feature being available, what are other authors using to solve the build speed issue? We're considering the [Drake package](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/307#issuecomment-495505707) but aren't sure if we have the time to implement prior to the spring 2021 semester. Has anyone had experience with Drake and Bookdown and can comment on the learning curve?

Any recommendations for either other packages or techniques we can try would be very much appreciated!

Comment: "It seems surprising there is still no built-in method for rebuilding a single book chapter" <- That's not true. There is a built-in method to build a single chapter (which has existed almost from day one in bookdown): https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/preview-a-chapter.html This is also what `bookdown::serve_book()` does by default. In general, before any effort to speed up things, you'd better take measurements and figure out where the slowness actually comes from (then cache the slow computation). Here is one way to do it: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/time-chunk.html

Comment: Thank you so much Yihui for replying. My understanding from the text is that previewing a chapter does not build cross-references - so that single rebuilt file made with preview_chapter() cannot be used as part of the live book. A build is still required after the preview to render the cross references.

Comment: Okay, I see now. Sorry I misunderstood it. You are right that you can't fully build a single chapter at the moment (not all cross-references will be resolved). I might be able to support this feature in the future. Please feel free to file an issue to https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown so I won't forget it. Thanks! (That said, it might still be worth finding out which chunks are slow and cache them accordingly)

Comment: @seschneck did you file an issue to github?, I was looking for it because I'd like to follow any progress on that front, but I can't find it. If you did, could you please link here to that discussion?